# How to convert QPixmap to base64 QString in Qt?

Tags: qt, base64, qstring, qpixmap

I am using QT 5.7 for a program where I have to convert a QPixmap to base64 QString format. I have tried to first convert the QPixmap to cv::Mat and then added my existing conversion flow.

```
Qpixmap pix;
cv::Mat pixData(pix.rows(),pix.cols(),CV_8UC3,pix.scanline());
                std::vector<uchar> IMbuffer;
                cv::imencode(".png", pixData, IMbuffer);
     QByteArray byteArray = QByteArray::fromRawData((const char*)IMbuffer.data(), IMbuffer.size());
                QString base64Image(byteArray.toBase64());
```

But it returns error:

```
error: 'class QPixmap' has no member named 'rows'
    cv::Mat pixData(pix.rows(),pix.cols(),CV_8UC3,pix.scanline());
                    ^
```

So it is clear that such conversion from QPixmap to cv::Mat is incompatible. So is there any easy way to convert QPixmap to base64 QString?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this;

```
 QBuffer buffer;
 buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
 pix.save(&buffer, "PNG");
 auto const encoded = buffer.data().toBase64();
```

Comment: It says  "error: 'QBuffer' was not declared in this scope
         QBuffer buffer; " Which header should be insluded for QBuffer?
         ^

Comment: @nocturnal_abu use `#include <QBuffer>`

Comment: Adding #include <QBuffer> compiles and works like a charm. Thanks a lot.